# ZSH variable substitution in adam explanation

Tags: command-prompt, zsh

I checked *<strike>R</strike>TFM* but couldn't understand it. The snippet is from the adam2 prompt from *ZSH*.

```
local prompt_line_1a_width=${#${(S%%)prompt_line_1a//(\%([KF1]|)\{*\}|\%[Bbkf])}}
```

What I understand is that a local variable `prompt_line_1a` is assigned the length result of the variable manipulation

```
${(S%%)prompt_line_1a//(\%([KF1]|)\{*\}|\%[Bbkf])}
```

But what happens to the original variable `prompt_line_1a` before length calculation is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, someone pointed out to me that I just have to look at the right place, the command consists of two parts:

```
${(flags)variablename}
```

and

```
${string//pattern/substitution}
```

where the first leads to:

- `S` search ungreedy
- `%%` Full prompt expansion (also expansion on the resulting words)

and for the latter `/substitution` can be dropped if no substitution but elemination should be applied.